# How can you plot a histogram with percentages in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, statistics, pie-chart

With `pie()`, a pie chart is plotted in Matlab. How can you plot a histogram that displays the same information (see plot)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a look at `bar(x,'stacked')`, although this will not display the ratios for you.

To display the ratio, I would say the easiest would be to use

```
set( gca, 'XTick', (1:n)-0.5, 'XTickLabel', ratios, 'XTickLabelRotation', 90 );
```

where `n` is the number of bars and `ratios` is a cell array of string labels with the ratio for each bar (eg `[1,2]`).